# Nvdimm memory but for laptop

Tags: laptop, memory

Looking for nvdimm but in the sodimm form factor.

Didn t found anything beside normal dimm. So I don t care about capacity or type first.

Comment: There are currently no laptop CPUs that support such kind of memory

Comment: @MechEng but there are laptops like Eurocomm which do support plain desktop and severs cpu. So this not relevant.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase that: there are no CPUs in laptops which could support NVDIMM. Eurocom is no exception here, they stopped using these larger server CPUs before NVDIMM became a thing.

Comment: @Romen except it s not with Intel optane you can remove the power cord and get the computer restarting as if nothing happend. This is an unrelated technology.

Comment: @MechEng disagree. In fact the question is because I m buying such laptop with such cpu. You should update your references.

Answer (score 1):

[NVDIMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVDIMM) is a new type of non-volatile memory designed to be compliant with full-sized DIMMs. It is part of the JEDEC standard.

If such a thing existed for SO-DIMM, it would probably be called NVSODIMM.

NVSODIMM [does not exist](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22NVSODIMM%22) as of February, 2020 when this answer was written.

I can't find any other trademark or official name for non-volatile SODIMM memory.

---

My guess is that the non-volatile memory is mostly being sold to big-business customers that run servers. Most of those servers would be using DIMMs, and the portion of servers using SODIMM is too small to justify the cost of designing and manufacturing something like "NVSODIMM".